# Passing a global reference to a function using Q in nodejs

Tags: node.js, scope, q

Can some one explain this to me ... have a global object and using some promises as below. When I reference the global in my function directly the reference is correct. When I try pass the reference it is not.

```
var globalObj = { ... }

function one() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  ...
  deferred.resolve();
  ...
  return deferred.promise;
}

function two {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  ...
  deferred.resolve();
  ...
  return deferred.promise;
}

function doSomthing() {
  var ref = globalObj;    // this is ok

  ...
}


one().
  .then(two)
  .then(doSomething) // (1) this is ok it works
```

the alternative is ...

```
var globalObj = { ... }

function one() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  ...
  deferred.resolve();
  ...
  return deferred.promise;
}

function two {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  ...
  deferred.resolve();
  ...
  return deferred.promise;
}

function doSomthing(someRef) {
  var sref = someRef;     // someRef is []
  ...
}


one().
  .then(two)
  .then(doSomethhing(globalObj)) // (2) this is not ok does not work
```

Note that there are two versions of code listedI tried (1) passing no reference and this was fine and (2) passing  a reference and this was not. I am not sure if this is a scoping issue or an issue with Q. Any ideas ?

Comment: it's not possible in js to have two versions of one function. Only the last one defined exists.

Comment: I edited the question as it was not that clear. I don't have 2 versions of the same function

Answer (score 0):

This

```
one()
  .then(two)
  .then(doSomething(globalObj));
```

should be

```
one()
  .then(two)
  .then(function () {
      return doSomethhing(globalObj);
  });
```

because you don't want to call `doSomething()` *immediately*, but that's exactly what the first variant does.

Comment: the first variant works. If so why does the second not work ?

Comment: Which first and second variants do you refer to? Mine or yours?

Comment: I am referring to mine

Comment: I thought the last sentence in my answer explained it. Think about the difference.

Comment: thanks, I didn't get it - I don't see how adding a closure helps. But will think about it ...

Comment: I don't "add a closure". I pass a function. You don't.

Comment: But in variant (1) I pass a reference to a function anyway. So what the difference ?

Comment: No, you pass a function result. What do you think that `doSomething(globalObj)` does?

Comment: Ok, so in my second variant the result has already been returned by the time the .then() is executed which is why the reference is empty ... got it, I thought I was passing a reference to the function. It's an odd paradigm for a non-JavaScript programmer. I would have thought that .then() would only be executed after the previous .then() and the call would be made at that point.

Comment: In your second attempt you give `.then()` the result of the function call. It's vital to realize that there is nothing asynchronous here. `one().then(x).then(y);` is completely synchronous. `.then()` is a facility that registers callback functions. It does not wait for anything.